# Testing the HomeTests class in tests.py has an error in line 29

Tags: python, django

I am continuing the Inspections/Defects project that I am doing for fun.  On line 29, the error says that HomeTests has no attribute Inspection, and I am trying to find out why.

Here is the tests.py file.

```
class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Inspection.objects.create(workOrderNum='123DER', partNumber='sd', customerName="RYANTRONICS", qtyInspected=10,qtyRejected=3)
        url = reverse('home')
        self.response = self.client.get(url)

    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)

    def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        inspection_topics_url = reverse(inspection_topics, kwargs={'pk': self.inspection.pk}) -> error occurs at this line 
        self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(inspection_topics_url))
```

I also have been looking in my views.py file to see if it was the source of the problem. I followed the guide at [Django URLs Advanced](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html#forms) but I had missed something.
Here is the views.py file in case you wanted to look at it.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Inspection

# Create your views here.

def home(request):

    inspections = Inspection.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'inspections': inspections})

def inspection_topics(request, pk):
    inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'inspection': inspection})
```

The views.py has two files, home.html and topics.html.  Here they are.

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Final Inspection Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Final Inspection Report</li>
      </ol>
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
          <tr>
            <th>Inspection</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Quanity Inspected</th>
            <th>Quantity Rejected</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for inspection in inspections %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ inspection.workOrderNum }}
                <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ inspection.partNumber }}</small>
              </td>
              <td class="align-middle">{{ inspection.customerName }}</td>
              <td class="align-middle">{{ inspection.qtyInspected }}</td>
              <td class="align-middle">
                {{ inspection.qtyRejected }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the home page where the inspections are stored.

And here is topics.html.

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ inspection.workOrderNum }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">Inspections</li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ inspection.workOrderNum }}</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I did this, the error I got was HomeTests has no attribute inspection, but the error that I should have gotten was False is not true: Couldn't find href=/inspections/1/.  How do I fix the HomeTests has no attribute error?

Comment: When I took that test out, the tests.py worked fine, but when I put it in, it says the error.  I do not know why.

Comment: I would like to know what this error means.

    def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        inspection_topics_url = reverse(inspection_topics, kwargs={'pk': self.inspection.pk}) -> error occurs at this line

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```py
self.inspection = Inspection.objects.create(
    workOrderNum='123DER',
    partNumber='sd',
    customerName='RYANTRONICS',
    qtyInspected=10,
    qtyRejected=3,
)
```

In general, for the `tests.py`, in the future:

```py
self.[model] = [model].object.create(attributes_of_model)
```

where [model] is the name of your model class in the models.py file and attributes_of_model are the attribute(s) that model has.